# I have a dataframe and I want to find the standard deviation for some specific cells

Tags: pandas, dataframe, standard-deviation

I'm trying to use pandas to find the standard deviation for the entries in some specific cells

I have tried using numPy's stdev like so:
numpy.std(df[columnName][j:i])

I have also tried using this:
df.std(axis=0)[columnName][j:i]

## Just pseudocode becuase my actual code is more confusing than necessary for this question:

```
df = loadIris()
for feat in df.columns:
     i = 0
     j = 0
     flower = df['flower'][i]
        while i < df.index.max():
            if df['flower'][i] == flower:
                i+=1
            else:  
                j = i    
                stand = df.std(axis=0)[feat][j:i]
                flower = df['flower'][i]
```

Comment: Show us a sample of the data, and the expected result for that sample.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just appending all of the values to a list and then calculating the standard deviation using statistics.stdev which you can get by importing statistics.